# Which query is more fast and less redundant in mySQL innoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
SELECT * FROM inv, clients 
WHERE   inv.client_id = clients.ID  
AND     ( inv.type = "STA"   
OR        inv.type = "FIN" )
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM invoice, clients 
WHERE  inv.client_id = clients.ID  
AND MATCH (inv.type) AGAINST ("STA FIN")
```

I know these are 2 questions, but maybe they go together

Comment: Why downvoting this question ? Doesn't it makes more sense to answer questions than playing police ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Use `inv.type IN ("STA", "FIN")` and `INDEX(client_id, type)`.

Long answer:

`MATCH...AGAINST` is terribly slow unless you have a `FULLTEXT` index on `type`.  However, this is a misuse of `FULLTEXT`, so I do not recommend it.

`AND     ( inv.type = "STA"   OR        inv.type = "FIN" )` is automatically turned into `AND inv.type IN ("STA", "FIN")`, which is reasonably fast.  If there is `INDEX(type)`, it might use that index and be really fast.  The utility of this depends on the cardinality -- "type" sounds like a column with very few different values, hence an index may be useless.

Another issue:  Don't use the antiquated "commajoin", use `JOIN...ON`:

```
SELECT *
    FROM invoice
    JOIN clients ON inv.client_id = clients.ID  -- How the tables relate
    WHERE inv.type IN ("STA", "FIN")  -- filtering
```

You should have

```
inv:  INDEX(client_id, type)
```

Using that 'composite' index takes care of both the ON and the WHERE, while avoiding the "low cardinality" issue I mentioned above.

Comment: type indeed has only 4 different terms, each of 3 chars. Okay so FULLTEXT search is useless. I will go on with this, thanks